# How to backup/restore a single database running with mysql 5.0 from one server to other available server?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I am currently using mysql server 5.0 with innodb storage engine. I want to backup a database from source server and restore the same to one of the available destination servers.

Option 1: Use innodb_file_per_table option in my .cnf and try to copy the table.ibd file to the other server and recover. I saw examples over other websites where it was being supported in mysql 5.6, but I am not sure if that is supported in mysql server 5.0. I tried the steps given in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html, but that did not work for me.

Option 2: Use mysqldump to get a dump of the database and use mysqlimport in the destination to perform mysql export/import. But, by doing so, I need to lock the database at source before performing the export. This can prevent any incoming requests to the source database while the mysqldump is ongoing.

I am still exploring other options, but I am not sure if option 1 is not viable due to mysql version 5.0 or because I am missing something.

Comment: Do _not_ attempt to take the .ibd files!  You _could_ take the _entire_ directory tree.

Comment: Sure, but I want to clarify if option 1 (copying Ibd files and recovering an individual database) is still an option with mysql 5.0?

Comment: 5.6 introduced "transportable tablespaces; 5.0 doe not.  (5.7 improves the interface.)  Upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html

You are talking about replication.

Comment: Thanks Chris!! But, I am wondering the link which you have shared explains about mysql's replication. But, in my case, I don't want to use mysql's replication and rather copy the database to another server. May be I didn't make the question clear, but I might have many destination servers out of which I would choose only one for replication. I don't think in that case mysql's replication would be helpful

Comment: @LokeshChandrakumar So you want all the other destination servers to remain out of date? That doesn't make sense. Use replication. That's what it's for.